# create login page once for first use after installing android application

Tags: java, android, sqlite, authentication, android-sqlite

I apologize if my questions seem to be repetitive. but, i'm still could not find any answer or tutorial that can help me in this.

i want to develop an application that needs to log in once after the user install the application. so, the user do not needs to login again if the user wants to use the application. Data of the user needs to be store in sqlite for login into the application.

is it any tutorial or anything that can help me on this.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**See this:** [Android User Session Management using Shared Preferences](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)

It has code samples and contains all the useful information for what you need. And there's **no need** to store the data in SQLite for what you described in your question. Just use **Shared Preferences**.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 4):

**Step 1:** create a `Splash Activity` and use it as the entry point to your application. NoDisplay makes it not visible for the user. It does not need a layout

```
        <activity
        android:name="your.package.name.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**Step 2:** in that `Activity` check whether the user is already logged in:

```
    public class Splash extends Activity {

private SharedPreferences prefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    prefs = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    if (!prefs.getBoolean("UserLoggedIn", false)) {

        startActivity(new Intent(this, UserLoginActivity.class));
        finish();

    } else {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, YourActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

}

       }
```

In your `Activity` you use for the user to log in, create a `boolean` value and set it to true after the log in is complete (example):

```
            ..........
           prefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(UserLoginActivity.this);
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("UserLoggedIn", true);

            editor.commit();
            startActivity(new Intent(UserLoginActivity.this,
                    NextActivity.class));
```

[here](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.de/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html) is an example of using `SharedPreferences`

Answer (score 0):

```
    Ok then open a database like this 

    public SQLiteDatabase sampleDB;
        public String COLUMN_ID="_id";
        public String COLUMN1="username";
        public String COLUMN2="password";
        public String TABLE_NAME="Androdata";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.login);


            sampleDB =  this.openOrCreateDatabase(TABLE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            boolean x=init(TABLE_NAME);// init is a function that checks db and return 
                                                 //false only for 1st time
            if(x==false)
            {
            createDB();
            insertDB();
            }

            }
    public boolean init(String tableName)
        {
            Cursor cursor = sampleDB.rawQuery("select DISTINCT tbl_name from sqlite_master where tbl_name = '"+tableName+"'", null);
            if(cursor!=null) {
                if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
                                    cursor.close();
                    return true;
                }
                            cursor.close();
            }
            return false;
        }
        private void insertDB() {
            sampleDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                    TABLE_NAME +
                    " Values ('0','Androviewer','viewer');");   
            System.out.println("Inserted data successfully....");
        }
        private void createDB() {
            sampleDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                    TABLE_NAME+ "(" + COLUMN_ID
                    + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN1
                    + " text not null,"+ COLUMN2
                    + " text not null);");
            System.out.println("Database created successfully....");
        }


    enter default value for id as 0 which is done here in insert function.

then all you need to do is just insert entered value in to database ok 

all the best

    check in start screen if its 0 open register page and get the values in to database otherwise go to app as your wish
```

Comment: don't you think a database is a bit too complicated approach just for managing a user logged in? SharedPreferences will do perfectly

Comment: Thats her wish ,melati asked for db thats why i posted this

Comment: not my wish :) probably the one of the topic starter though he doesn't seem to know much about ways of persisting data in Android

Comment: :) yup ,both are here .choose whatever as user wish

Comment: thank you for both of you. act im beginner in android. and im not very sure how to develop when the user me for it.